# How to generate a SHA256 encrypted string in C#?

Tags: c#, sha256

For a project I need to generate a SHA256 encrypted string in C#.
The requirements are Key: todaysDate and Value: "exampleString".

How can i realize that in C#? As far as I see the SHA256-Class does not contain a property for key in C#.

Comment: Sounds like homework... You need to study the SHA256 algorithm and learn about public keys (SHA256) and private keys (UUID, perhaps.)

Comment: @odixon Where is a "public key" SHA256 is a cryptographic hash function.

Comment: @danielmunich Perhaps you mean AES with a 256-bit key, SHA256 is not an encryption primitive.

Answer (score 3):

[SHA256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) isn't an encryption algorithm, it's a [hash algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). In other words, it's a *one way* function whose job is to take an input of any length and produce an output of fixed length with low collisions that's always the same for the same input. Thus, it doesn't receive a key as an input because the nature of hashing is quite different from that of encryption.

If you want to encrypt something with a key and later decrypt it by having the same key, look into symmetric encryption like [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) (e.g. using [the `AesManaged` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

You should do your own homework. If we do it for you, you learn nothing.

Also, as Theodoros mentioned, SHA256 is a hash, not encryption. A hash is a cryptographic checksum that is used to validate or compare data. It can not be reversed into the original plaintext, which is a requirement of encryption.

> How can i realize that in C#? As far as I see the SHA256-Class does not contain a property for key in C#.

Either you or the person who gave you the assignment doesn't understand what is being asked.

SHA256 doesn't have a key or a value, it only has data going in and a hash coming out. No matter how much data you run through it, the size of the hash does not change, although it's value does. You can think of a hash as a fingerprint for a particular dataset.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this:

```
public static string sha256_hash(string sValue) {
  StringBuilder oResHash = new StringBuilder();

  using (SHA256 oHash = SHA256Managed.Create()) {
    Encoding oEnc = Encoding.UTF8;
    byte[] baResult = oHash.ComputeHash(oEnc.GetBytes(sValue));

    foreach (byte b in baResult)
      oResHash.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
  }

  return oResHash.ToString();
}
```